# Lambda Step Functions: Fire & Forget pattern

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have a Python-based Lambda (core Lambda) serving a synchronous API. The API is triggered from an user interactive application. I now need to add some logging & metrics (slightly compute intensive) to the Lambda. I don't want the core Lambda to be delayed by this. I want to push this into a new Lambda (logging Lambda). What I want is- core Lambda completes its work, triggers the logging Lambda (fire & forget) and returns the response to API call immediately. The end state (success/failure) of the logging Lambda is irrelevant.

Can **"Step Functions**" achieve this? The core & logging Lambdas have their own end state and I'm not sure if the "Step" function pattern can accommodate this.

Comment: i'd suggest using SNS. The message delivery to SNS will still be synchronous but the computation in your logging lambda will be async.

Comment: @kkesley- Thanks, this is an option I can try

Answer (score 2):

You can start an [asynchronous Lambda function invocation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html) using `"InvocationType": "Event"` in your Invoke parameters. To do that in Step Functions, the ASL code looks like this:

```
{
  "StartAt": "Invoke Lambda function asynchronously",
  "States": {
    "Invoke Lambda function asynchronously": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "Parameters": {
        "FunctionName": "myFunction",
        "Payload.$": "$",
        "InvocationType": "Event"
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Having an async Lambda Task (as shown above) after your core Lambda Task seems like it should work. To make sure the logging Lambda failing doesn't affect the overall workflow, you can add a Catcher to it on `States.ALL` and redirect to a `Succeed` state.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html#error-handling-fallback-states

Comment: Were you able to send a custom payload when you used `InvocationType` as `Event` ? Currently I'm not able to send a payload when using `Event`.

Answer (score 0):

If the secondary Lambda is purely invoked for logging purposes and the state machine is not dependent on its output, you could invoke the secondary Lambda from within your primary Lambda, then return from the primary Lambda. This way your state machine doesn't need to know about the logging steps and you can "fire and forget" before resuming your workflow.

Comment: @aws-jordan- Thanks. Does this require step function or is it just the core Lambda invoking the logging Lambda asynchronously? I didn't know it was possible to asynchronously trigger a child lambda.